# Is there such a thing as a nullable bool in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, nullable

I am working through my new MVC book and of course, the samples are all in c# as usual.

There is a line of code that says

```
public bool? WillAttend { get; set; }
```

The author explains that the question mark indicates that this is a nullable (tri-state) bool that can be true, false. or null.  (A new C# 3 convention.)

Does vb.net support any convention like this.  Certainly I can declare a boolean in vb.net and I can explicitly set it to Null (Nothing in vb.net).

What's the difference.  IS there more to it in c#.  Advantages?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. `bool?` is just shorthand [syntax for a nullable value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx): i.e. `Nullable<bool>`
2. In VB.NET you can use either one: `Boolean?` or `Nullable(Of Boolean)`.

You can write it like this with a backing property:

```vb
Private _willAttend As Nullable(Of Boolean)
Public Property WillAttend As Nullable(Of Boolean)
    Get
        Return _willAttend
    End Get
    Set(value As Nullable(Of Boolean))
        _willAttend = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Or just use an [auto-implemented property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx) like this:

```vb
Public Property WillAttend As Boolean?
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the property declaration too...that would have been the next question.

Answer (score 44):

You can declare a nullable value 3 ways in VB:

```vb
Dim ridesBusToWork1? As Boolean
Dim ridesBusToWork2 As Boolean?
Dim ridesBusToWork3 As Nullable(Of Boolean)
```

Further Reading: [MSDN - Nullable Value Types (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245).

Comment: Hey - I never knew you could add the ? after the variable name?  Nice!  I learned something new today.

Comment: Very helpful for confirmation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Nullables are available since .NET 2.0. In that version Microsoft implemented Generics (Nullable is a Generic type). Since .NET 3.0 you are able to use the ? in VB.NET too (previously you were only able to use Nullable(of Boolean)).

So as said by Lucas Aardvark in .NET 3.0 you are able to use 3 declarations of nullables, but in .NET 2.0 only 1 being

```
Dim myBool as Nullable(of Boolean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nullable is used used on value types such as ints, bools and etc which don't support null assignments. This is generally very handy when you methods return integers. If the result of a method is invalid, you can simply return a nullable int set to null instead of a negative integer, which may end up being a valid result in the long run. That's pretty much the only advantage that comes to mind. Others have posted how to do this in VB.NET. I won't go into that.