# Question mark on a type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, types

I've used this quite innocently for a while now without actually knowing much about it, but basically it's:

```vb
Private _SomeFieldDate As DateTime?
```

or...

```vb
Private _SomeFieldInt As Int32?
```

I realise that the question mark on the end allows the definition of a `Null` or rather `Nothing` value to be assigned to the field, but what exactly happens here, and what is the term for this question mark?

(PS: I did try looking for this on SO but couldn't find it; if this has previously been posted then would you mind popping a link to the post in an answer, please?)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx

Comment: Adding the question mark turns it into a nullable type, which means that either it is a variabletype object, or it is null

Comment: There is no terminology for that `?`, it's basically, as you state, as marker to declare a nullable type.

Comment: One possible duplicate: [What does the ? mean after a type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079334/what-does-the-mean-after-a-type) Note that C# and VB.NET are not different on this topic.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2cf62fcy.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there such a thing as a nullable bool in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225471/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-nullable-bool-in-vb-net)

Comment: Thanks everyone - that's cleared that up.  I see that the question mark can actually be either side of the assignment, also, so that you can declare your field/variable so: `myvar? As Boolean`, or the type `myvar As Boolean?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primitive types such as integers and booleans cannot generally be null, but the corresponding nullable types (nullable integer and nullable boolean, respectively) can also assume the NULL value. NULL is frequently used to represent a missing value or invalid value, such as from a function that failed to return or a missing field in a database, as in NULL in SQL.

Source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type

Nullable types in C# - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's called a nullable and the question mark is short for

```
Nullable<T>
```

More info [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)